# Storm-Computation time inside bolt execute() method

Tags: apache-storm

I have been testing with Storm for our lab project.
And when I used Storm bolt to perform some computational task,
I found that the time it took to run the computation outside of Storm is approximately 10 times less than that inside a Storm bolt execute() method.

And I also tried this small piece of snippet inside the execute() method of a bolt:

```
Random rd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
double  count =rd.nextDouble();
for( int i=0;i <50000000;i++ ) {
    count *= rd.nextDouble();
}
```

Above code took around 1000 ms to finish inside Storm, while only took around 10 ms to finish outside of the Storm enviroment.

Is this even heavy computational task for a Storm bolt?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point. Can you come up with a trival test that runs better on one node? Sure, but you'd never use it for that. If your computation runs fine on one node then don't use Storm because it is overkill.

Storm is a **distributed** realtime computation system. If you need to process an insane amount of data in real-time and in a scalable, fault-tolerant way using many machines then use Storm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  
I did run the test on one node, that gave me the same result. 
The fact is we need to process a large amount of data, and also for each tuple, we need 10 ms to process it. 
The part I don't understand is Storm takes 100 times as much of time to do the same processing job.

Answer (score 0):

ah, this is a stupid mistake of mine, the runnning time in the execute() method is fine for the simple computation.

But the really processing we are doing inside execute() is still several times slower than outside of Storm eviroment. In this processing, we actually called JNI methods, don't konw if that is the reason why.